# jquery horizontal slider white space issue

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I am working on project where in horizontal slider I need to show multiple products blocks. Since there are not fix number of products I have given width of div 1360% now what problem I am facing here is if products are less than white spaces showing in div which is obvious of that 1360% div size. If I keep width of div auto then design structure messes. How can I avoid this white space?

[image]

Live site Link - http://foxboxretail.in/

css

```
.common-blocks {
    width: 100%;
    width: 1366%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

In above css if I keep width auto & max-width:1360% then content gets overlap

Jquery

```
<script>
        var registerEvents = function () {
            $(".next").off("click").on("click", function (event) {
                if ($(this).hasClass('disable')) return;
                $(this).addClass('disable');
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $(event.target).removeClass('disable');
                }, 510);
                var targetBlock = $(event.target).parents().children(".common-blocks");
                var leftMargin = parseInt(targetBlock.css("marginLeft") || 0);
                var numberOfBlocks = targetBlock.children(".blocks").length; //    Total Number of blocks 
                var displayCount = 3;//Number of blocks displaying at a time
                if (leftMargin <= (numberOfBlocks - displayCount) * (-1024))  // -300 width   of    block in left direction
                    return;
                targetBlock.css("marginLeft", parseInt(leftMargin - 1024) + "px")
            });
            $(".prev").off("click").on("click", function (event) {
                if ($(this).hasClass('disable')) return;
                $(this).addClass('disable');
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $(event.target).removeClass('disable');
                }, 510);
                var targetBlock = $(event.target).parents().children(".common-blocks");
                var leftMargin = parseInt(targetBlock.css("marginLeft") || 0);
                if (leftMargin == 0)
                    return;
                targetBlock.css("marginLeft", parseInt(leftMargin + 1024) + "px")
            });

        }();
    </script>
```

Because it's dynamic content I can't display markup since code gets lengthy

Comment: min-width max width can help

Answer (score 0):

change css:

```
.blocks {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 249px !important;
    margin: 5px 0px 0 1px;
}
```

Comment: My current css uses same settings. But It's not working.

Comment: apply this in live url??

Comment: I did. Nothing worked. Show me your screen shot of working demo

Answer (score 0):

see image for change css class:

[image]

Comment: What you are showing me is first phase of slide. Can you just slide it till the last product in experience section i.e adlabs Imagica there you can see Products get over but still it keeps on sliding that I want to eliminate

Comment: Hey sun, in first remove white space and second displayed to your change CSS